# Opt-out of IntelliJ IDEA EAP program

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed an IntelliJ IDEA EAP build because I was interested in a specific bug fix. Now that it was fixed and made it into the stable builds, I'm happy with the stable builds and don't want to be prompted for EAP / Preview updates anymore.

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2 (Ultimate).

Is it possible to switch to the stable update channel without re-downloading/reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an option in the settings: it's possible to choose the update channel under Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates.